# Source of Modim D’Rabbanan

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot

The Shulchan Aruch notes ([Orach Chaim 127:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3299227/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-127-Laws-Relating-to-Modim-DeRabbanan.htm))  that Modim D’Rabbanan was ‘ordained by many sages”.  But what is the source?

Comment: https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2007-03-30Tefila_Newsletter.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Sotah 40a.

> בזמן ששליח צבור אומר מודים העם מה הם אומרים אמר רב מודים אנחנו לך ה' אלהינו על שאנו מודים לך ושמואל אמר אלהי כל בשר על שאנו מודים לך רבי סימאי אומר יוצרנו יוצר בראשית על שאנו מודים לך נהרדעי אמרי משמיה דרבי סימאי ברכות והודאות לשמך הגדול על שהחייתנו וקיימתנו על שאנו מודים לך רב אחא בר יעקב מסיים בה הכי כן תחיינו ותחננו ותקבצנו ותאסוף גליותינו לחצרות קדשך לשמור חוקיך ולעשות רצונך בלבב שלם על שאנו מודים לך אמר רב פפא הילכך נימרינהו לכולהו
>   At the time the Leader says Modim, what to the people say? Rav said, "...". Shmuel said, "...". Rabbi Simai said, "...". Nehardai said in the name of Rabbi Simai, "...". Rabbi Acha Bar Yaakov finished with "...". Rabbi Papa said, "Therefore let's say all of them."

Comment: Also same sort of story in Yerushalmi Berakhot 1:5